# How to format date using NSDateFormatter iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter, uidatepicker

I tried to use the `NSDateFormatter` to format a date that selected from a `UIDatepicker`. But the formatted result giving a `nil`.

```
-(NSString *)formatDateWithString:(NSString *)date{ 
    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    NSDate *formattedDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:date];
    return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:formattedDate];
}
```

date input is `2016-04-22 16:30:36 +0000`(after selected from UIDatePicker). How may I fix this?

Comment: Actually `UIDatePicker` has a `var date: NSDate` property

Comment: or in Objective-C: `@property(nonatomic, strong) NSDate *date`

Comment: `@"yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss"` should be `@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`. `MMM` would be the abbreviated name Apr

Comment: bookmark this!: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-29.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table

Comment: @vikingosegundo Slightly out of date. The latest (currently) is http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment you can get the NSDate directly from the UIDatePicker and pass that date directly in the formatter

```
NSDateFormatter * formatter =  [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date];//pass the date you get from UIDatePicker
```

If you want to convert the same way you have mentioned in the question you can try like this:

```
-(NSString *)formatDateWithString:(NSString *)date{
    NSDateFormatter * formatter =  [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"];
    NSDate * convrtedDate = [formatter dateFromString:date];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:convrtedDate];
    return dateString;
}
```